# Type inference of pair (product) types

Tags: type-theory, type-inference, unification

I am looking into Hindler-Milney type system and I am trying to add support for
the pair type. In Pierces book, he introduces special language constructs for creation of pairs and getting their elements.

What I am interested in is the following. What if I don't introduce new constructs, yet use special functions with this signatures:

$$pair: \alpha \rightarrow \beta \rightarrow \alpha \times \beta $$

$$proj1: \alpha \times \beta \rightarrow \alpha$$

$$proj2: \alpha \times \beta \rightarrow \beta $$

If I use Wand's algorithm for type inference, after collecting all equations between type expressions and solving it a bit, I get the following equation
for $((pair\; 2\;) 4): \tau$:

$$\alpha \rightarrow \beta \rightarrow \alpha \times \beta = Int \rightarrow Int \rightarrow \tau$$

It seems to me that the unification algorithm should infer at the end that $\tau = Int \times Int$. Is this true?

Do I really need a special construct for pairs? Is there something conceptually wrong with this? Probably their is, so it would be great if someone could point me out.

Note that I would also prefer using special constructs as that way looks cleaner and easier to program with; this question is just for my complete understanding of the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use things like **pair**, **proj** ... as constants only. That works
very well conceptually. Nevertheless, there are reasons why 
programming languages tend to use special syntactic forms for the like of
products:

- Readability, e.g. **( M, N )** reads more natural than **pair M N** to
  some.
- For efficient reductions. It is possible to code the reductions for
  pairs up in pure$\lambda$-calculus, but that's usually not as efficient.
- Finally, you'd need a polymorphic typing system for this to work.

As an aside, the formalisation of logics in interactive proof assistants 
like [Isabelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabelle_%28proof_assistant%29) is based on a similar idea, called [logical frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_framework).

Comment: Nice answer. Just one question related to your last remark. Are those logical frameworks based on Curry-Howard isomorphism?

Comment: @bellpeace No, logical frameworks is orthogonal to the Curry-Howard correspondence. For example Isabelle isn't even based on Curry-Howard. Logical frameworks shows how much further you can push the idea that your original question is about.